# Referencing XAML using a string C#

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a button which, when pressed will change the source of a certain Image. I'm currently calling a method which takes the parameter of a string (the x:Name of the image which I would like to change). However, in the method, I don't know how I can access that string, as it doesn't show up when I try to change the source.

```
button1_Click(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
  changeSource(imageSeven);
}

private void changeSource(string imageIndx)
{ 
  imageIndx.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\myfolder\folder1\changed image"));
}
```

Comment: the imageIndex is string type, which does not have "Source" Property.

Comment: `imageIndx` is a string. Do you have a list of images too? Could you show that code?

Comment: Instead of passing a string with the name of the Image UI element, could you not pass the respective Image UI element itself to the `changeSource` method? If not, why exactly can you not? (And, as haldo already advised, show your code/XAML that defines/creates the Image UI elements so we can understand your problem/difficulties)